# I want to add x customers on Prestashop via code but with extra fields

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to add customers with a code but the PrestaShop is giving me a bug.
I'm using PHP and XML

```
$XMLRQString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
    '<x:Winmax4GetEntitiesRQ xmlns:x="urn:Winmax4GetEntitiesRQ">'.
                    '</x:Winmax4GetEntitiesRQ >';
                    $Params=array(
                    'CompanyCode'=>'',
                    'UserLogin'=>'',
                    'UserPassword'=>'',
                    'Winmax4GetEntitiesRQXML'=> $XMLRQString
                    );
                    $return = $client->GetEntities($Params);
                    $XMLRSString = new SimpleXMLElement($return->GetEntitiesResult);

foreach ($XMLRSString->Entities->Entity as $entity)
{   
    $default_lang= Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
                    
    $customer=new Customer();

    $customer->email= $entity->Email;

    $customer->lastname= $entity->EntityType;

    $customer->firstname= [$default_lang => $entity->Name];

    $customer->contribuinte= $entity->TaxPayerID;

    $customer->passwd= $entity->TaxPayerID;

    $customer->active = 1;

    $customer->add();
}
```

> ERROR: (1/1) ContextErrorException Warning: preg_match() expects
> parameter 2 to be string, array given
>
> in Validate.php line 172
>
> at ValidateCore::isCustomerName(array(object(SimpleXMLElement))) in
> ObjectModel.php line 1149
>
> at ObjectModelCore->validateField('firstname',
> array(object(SimpleXMLElement))) in ObjectModel.php line 981
>
> at ObjectModelCore->validateFields() in ObjectModel.php line 284
>
> at ObjectModelCore->getFields() in ObjectModel.php line 551
>
> at ObjectModelCore->add(true, true) in Customer.php line 264
>
> at CustomerCore->add() in create_clients.php line 66

Comment: Have you tried just `$customer->firstname= (string)$entity->Name;`

Comment: lol, thank-q so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing values from SimpleXML, if you just refer to the element itself by it's tag name - this will be an instance of SimpleXMLElement.  As you want the actual content of the element, the simplest way to do this is to cast it to a string...

```
$customer->firstname= (string)$entity->Name;
```